# Can't get longitude and latitude from array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to store the latitude and the longitude from an array where its length is sometimes 1 ,sometimes 2 or 3 .

Here is the code:

```
    var latitude,longitude;
    $.each(data.results, function (i, item) {
    var name = item.from_user;
    var img = item.profile_image_url;
    var text=item.text;
    var profile_img=item.profile_image_url;
    var url=(item.entities.urls.length > 0 ? item.entities.urls[0].url : '');
    Placemaker.getPlaces(text,function(o){
    console.log(o);
    if (typeof(o.match!=='undefined') ||(o.length==1)){
     latitude=o.match.place.centroid.latitude, longitude=o.match.place.centroid.longitude; 
     console.log(latitude,longitude);}
     else if (typeof(o.match[0]!=='undefined') ||(o.match.length==2)){
        latitude=o.match[0].place.centroid.latitude, longitude=o.match[0].place.centroid.longitude; 
     console.log(latitude,longitude);
     }

    });
    array.push({name:name,img:img,text:text,latitude:latitude,longitude:longitude,profile_img:profile_img,url:url});
```

From this code I get  only the latitude & longitude values when the array length is 1. So only the first if is executed. I am trying to fix the others so that I can get values from the other arrays as well, since when I use console.log to output the array, the values of latitude & longitude are not there. I guess that the loop has to finish getting all the values before putting them into the array.

I am trying to output the tweets on the google map via the tweets location. I am not using geocode but yahoo placemaker to geolocate the location from the text of the tweet.

here is a snapshot of the placemaker array structure http://www.flickr.com/photos/codepo8/3553188917/

this is the other array that am trying to get values Object { match=[2]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`typeof(o.match!=='undefined')` is always "boolean"
I think you want
`typeof(o.match)!=='undefined'` or just  `typeof o.match!=='undefined'`

Comment: thats not a problem am trying to get the values from an array who has 2 objects inside of it like this ---->  Object { match=[2]}

Comment: It is the reason that the first 'if' is always true

Comment: well this one else if (typeof o.match!=='undefined' || o.match.length==2){  doesnt work .. it gives me TypeError: o.match is undefined